# Выбор концепции архитектуры системы управления контентом (CMS) для микросервисной архитектуры

Tags: postgresql, cms, микросервисы

При реализации достаточно крупной системы на микросервисах столкнулись со следующей проблемой: необходимо реализовать систему управления контентом для системы. Сервисы пишутся на различных ЯП: C# (ASP.NET Core), PHP (Laravel), Go. Видится 2 варианта решения проблемы:

1. Реализация бэкенд библиотек, выполняющих все необходимые для CMS операции для каждого ЯП и каждой ORM, фронт общий, библиотеки работают по единым интерфейсам, возникнут большие проблемы с обеспечением одинакового состояния библиотек для разных языков/ORM. Библиотека подключается к каждому сервису, у которого есть справочники.
2. Реализация единого CMS сервиса, связанного с базами данных других микросервисов напрямую. Нарушается концепция микросервисной архитектуры, но при этом решается проблема совместимости и сложности составления справочников, которые содержат в себе данные из различных сервисов. Кроме того уменьшается сетевая задержка на лишние API запросы к сервисам.

Оба варианта выглядят как полные костыли. Есть ли какой-то адекватный вариант решения этой проблемы? Или может можно усовершенствовать какой-то способ из перечисленных выше?

Comment: Не вижу ответа на главный вопрос - зачем тут микросервисы?

Comment: Это сложная распределенная система, архитектурное решеение было выбрано после долгого анализа множества факторов.

Comment: Добавьте этот анализ и факторы в вопрос. Также ваши опции не ясны. Если у вас микросервисы, что мешает сделать обычный bff?

Comment: api gateway не нарушает концепцию https://wac-cdn.atlassian.com/dam/jcr:d76e535a-b5ad-473a-b697-26dab8b73c18/microservice_architecture_v2.png?cdnVersion=1483 "Приложения взаимодействуют с микросервисами через API-интерфейсы REST, которые публикует каждый микросервис. Приложения обращаются к API-интерфейсам микросервисов через API-шлюз," https://www.atlassian.com/ru/microservices/microservices-architecture